# "In bocca al lupo!" - FONTI delle varie interpretazioni?

Tags: phrase-origin

Salve! Come da titolo, vorrei delle fonti *accreditate* (es. studi universitari, enciclopedie...) che trattino dell'origine del famoso modo di dire "in bocca al lupo".

**UPDATE:** *Non mi occorrono risposte (o commenti) sull'interpretazione ma eventuali fonti bibliografiche accreditate che trattino dell'argomento*

L'Accademia della Crusca pone le radici del detto nelle usanze dei cacciatori, come *augurio* (riuscire a trovare un Lupo è davvero raro, quindi equivale a "Buona Caccia"). La negatività della figura del lupo pare essersi rafforzata durante il Medioevo anche se fin dalla cultura classica (per non parlare della Bibbia!) il lupo è il male e l'agnello/la pecora il bene.

Ho trovato anche altre interpretazioni (che sinceramente preferisco) delle quali, appunto, non trovo una fonte accreditata:

- I genitori di lupo per spostare i cuccioli e portarli al sicuro li prendono in bocca (quindi il luogo più sicuro per un lupetto) => augurare di trovarsi in bocca ad un lupo significa essere al sicuro.
- Romolo e Remo, nella leggenda, sono stati salvati da una lupa  => augurare di trovarsi in bocca ad un lupo significa essere al sicuro.
- La bocca di lupo, in gergo marinaresco, era una lavagna sulla quale venivano riportati i nomi delle persone e delle cose rientrate da un lungo viaggio in mare => augurare ad una persona che tutto vada *in porto* (= tornare sana e salva ecc.).

**UPDATE:** *Ho già letto le altre domande e risposte. Sto cercando fonti accreditate oltre a quelle dell'Accademia della Crusca che sostengano le tre versioni di cui sopra.*

Comment: Domanda correlata a questa: http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1879/707

Comment: @Charo avevo già visto quella domanda e le risposte connesse, grazie! Però esse non soddisfano la mia richiesta: vorrei delle **fonti** (= riferimenti bibliografici o nomi di autori sempre che esistano).

Comment: Immagino che tu abbia già letto questo: http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_bocca_al_lupo

Comment: Quello che dice la Crusca (almeno [qui](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/sullorigine-formula-bocca-lupo); non so se ci sia tornata altrove) non sembra che sia un generico augurio di trovare un lupo, bensì un augurio di uscirne indenni espresso per antifrasi: una sorta di scaramanzia, se vogliamo. Lì questa tesi si dice confermata da vari dizionari della lingua italiana e dei modi di dire.

Comment: Una espressione equivalente a _in bocca al lupo_, in tedesco, è _Hals- und Beinbruch_, che significa _rottura di collo e di gamba_. Chiaramente anche questo un "augurio di uscirne indenni espresso per antifrasi", come dice @DaG

Comment: Simile l'inglese. Un augurio tradizionale agli attori è "break a leg."

Comment: @Alessandro Macilenti,  DaG e Walter Tross leggete meglio la mia domanda ;-)
Non ho chiesto il significato ma le FONTI (a parte la Crusca).

Comment: Infatti, Beatrix, queste non sono risposte, ma commenti. Comunque la Crusca cita altre quattro fonti. Più quella che citavo nella mia risposta all'altra domanda sul lupo, fanno sei, tutte concordi. Comunque speriamo di trovarne ancora altre.

Comment: @DaG Ringrazio per la segnalazione ma alla fine della domanda, appunto, ho scritto "**oltre** all'accademia della crusca" ;) Speravo ci fosse qualche letterato a conoscenza di un qualche autore latino o qualche libro specifico sui modi di dire.. ho visto quello che si trova sul web, sennò non avrei postato la domanda ;-)

Comment: A Beatri', sappiamo leggere. :-) Ti capisco benissimo, anche perché pure io ho posto [una domanda simile](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3859/candaulismo-o-candaulesimo-o-altro) (non come argomento, ma nel senso di cercare fonti) e incontrato incomprensioni simili a quelle che credi di incontrare tu. Ma fammi sottolineare che questi sono solo commenti, e quindi non sono tenuti a rispondere nei termini della domanda (sennò sarebbero risposte :-)), ma a fare osservazioni pertinenti ma non risolutive. Bene? Buon proseguimento di indagine.

Comment: E, Beatrix, ognuno commenta quello che può e vuole, nei limiti delle regole e dell'etichetta di questo sito. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe here you will not find anything other than *comments*: perhaps it is best to look at the library. Try to look at the [link](http://cultura.biografieonline.it/perche-si-dice-in-bocca-al-lupo/) but it unfortunately not cite sources.

Comment: Your answer is not very useful for me, however, the link is cute. On the Web actually it is not anything other than references to the best-known version, maybe you're right.