# "Related question" in italiano

Tags: translation, phrase-request

Scrivendo un commento a [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5116/707), mi sono accorta di non saper come dire "related question" in italiano. Là ho messo "domanda correlata a questa", ma non sono sicura se questa espressione sia corretta o se si possa esprimere questo concetto in un altro modo. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire il mio dubbio?

Comment: Tecnicamente "domande correlate" va bene fintanto che non stai usando l'aggettivo nel senso di correlazione statistica (io preferirei "domande simili").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Domanda correlata a questa" è perfetto.
Volendo usare un sinonimo, potresti ricorrere a "Domanda simile a questa".